# Android Studio / bug con Navigation Drawer y Tab Layout

Tags: android, fragment, navigation

Tengo una **Navigation Drawer activity** la cual, con sus **items**, me redireccionan a fragments vacíos y otros a **fragments tabbeados** con los cuales tengo problemas.

Cuando estoy **navegando** por mi aplicación y toco varias veces (3 o más) un item que me lleva a un fragment tabbeado, estos comienzan a **funcionar mal**. Comienzan a dejar de mostrar el contenido que hay en cada uno de los fragments **correspondientes a cada tab**.

Lo curioso es que este **error** de **"no carga de vistas"** solo sucede cuando entro a un fragment tabbeado después de haber navegado un rato por mi aplicación.

**Datos extra:**

1- El error de "no carga de vistas" no se genera con fragments que no están tabbeados (correspondientes a otros items del navigation drawer).

2- Al abrir la aplicación, la primera (o a veces la segunda) vez que ingreso a estos fragments tabbeados, las vistas se muestran normalmente.

**Desde ya agradezco mucho la lectura de mi problema.**

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado y un fragmento de código?, viendo que estas haciendo es mas fácil ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: No hay código relevante para mostrar. El código del Navigation Drawer es el que crea android studio por defecto, al igual que el fragment con tabs que es la actividad que crea también android studio por defecto, solo que no es una actividad, sino que es un fragment.

Comment: es solo una actividad??

Comment: NO, fragments..